# Audio resample 11025Hz to 48000Hz with ffmpeg of other ways

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, resampling

I have many wav files 11025Hz 8bit and I like to resample to 48000Hz becouse I like to increase the high frequency.

I ask if ffmpeg can do it. I have found this:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html

but It is not clear if can be useful. I ask if ffmpeg can do it with good result or I need to find other specific software.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to increase sample rate? However, ffmpeg is a perfect tool for this job

Comment: It's pointless to do so.  You can't increase the high frequency content in the sound because it isn't there to begin with.  No doubt whatever you are listening on resamples upwards to 44.1 kHz or 48 kHz on the fly when you play it back anyway.

Comment: @Brad you are right. However, there are useful cases, not mentioned in the question, and I decided to respond anyway. 1) play audio with live digital mixers  2) Old car players 3) Old pro audio multitrack softwares do not use audio with sampling freq lower than 22050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i yourfile.wav -osr 48000 outfile.wav`
The switch `-osr` is for output sample rate.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to upsample from 11K to 44K

`ffmpeg -i in.wav -isr 11025 -osr 44000 out-44k.wav` Failed :(

This however worked

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -isr 11025 -ar 44000 -osr 44000 out-44k.wav
```

Comment: maybe the original file wasn't 11025?